# Postgresql Get max value of each group with multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table

```
CREATE table test
(
    random_number INT,
    band VARCHAR(255),
    member_name VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES(2300,'Metallica', 'Kirk');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2000,'Metallica', 'Lars');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2500,'Metallica', 'James');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2800,'Metallica', 'Roberto');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(100,'SkidRow', 'Sebastian');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(140,'SkidRow', 'Rachel');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(110,'SkidRow', 'Scott');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(150,'SkidRow', 'Dave');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(100,'SkidRow', 'Rob');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(500,'Motorhead', 'Lemmy');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(100,'Motorhead', 'Mikkey');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(200,'Motorhead', 'Phil');
```

How could I get the biggest `random_number` of each band and return something like this:

```
random_number |   band    | member_name
-----------------------------------------
     2800     | Metallica |  Roberto
     150      | SkidRow   |  Dave
     500      | Motorhead |  Lemmy
```

Comment: Check out window functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (band) t.*
from test t
order by band, random_number desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=743f3c502a00f74788e212499f18a390) is a db<>fiddle.

`distinct on` is a very handy Postgres extension.  For performance on large datasets, you want an index on `(band, random_number desc)`.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it orders the results based on the alphabetic order of the band name. In my case I wanted to have a DISTINCT name and at the same time results based on the descending random_number. I achieved it with nested SELECT: `select random_number, band from (select distinct on (band) t.* from test t order by band, random_number desc) as nested order by random_number desc;` [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6296d47f8e0e5db9af33ed39c049ec5b) is the modified db<>fiddle

Answer (score 6):

Find the maximum `random_number` by grouping and join to the table:

```
select t.* 
from test t inner join (
  select band, max(random_number) maxnum from test group by band
) g
on g.band = t.band and g.maxnum = t.random_number
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=4dbb393622fb7f6d2ee8240f2fc6845c)

Answer (score -1):

Use `MAX()`

```sql
SELECT max(random_number), band FROM test GROUP BY band
```

See: https://rextester.com/BEZD44968

Result would be:

```
no  max band
1   2800 Metallica
2   500 Motorhead
3   150 SkidRow
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I would like to see the `member_name` in the result.

Comment: Ah, then use distinct. See @Gordon's answer.

Comment: When I try to test the code via the link you provided, I get: `"Error(s), warning(s):
This language is for patrons only. Visit https://www.patreon.com/rextester for more information."`